# How do I convert audiobooks from mp3 to m4b?

Tags: 11.10, ipod, conversion, audiobooks

I've moved from Windows to Ubuntu and I have problems converting my new books (in mp3) to m4b. There are a lot of Windows applications which could do that, but what about Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

On the linux side this is supported by some versions of libfaac or the faac binary.  [Here](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Converting_mp3_audio_books_to_m4b) is a link for gentoo.  I don't know if the out of the box libfaac on ubuntu will do it, but I kind of doubt it.  A recompile or medibuntu repo might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

While there is many Windows based programs that can perform this via a GUI from what I can find on Linux or Ubuntu you will have to revert to a command line to achieve it.

You can try the method detailed by aking1012 but as he states I also doubt it will work on ubuntu - but you could try.

I found a [step by step guide that details coverting the mp3 to m4b](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/41095.aspx) by first converting to a .pcm file *then* converting it to m4b but this seems a long way to go and requires a lot of disk space.

An easier guide is on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1867780) which requires ffmpeg, imagemagick and mp3wrap and a script that is downloadable from the link to run.

> mp4tags etc: wget
>   http://mp4v2.googlecode.com/files/mp4v2-1.9.1.tar.bz2
>
> ```
> tar -xf mp4v2-1.9.1.tar.bz2 
> cd mp4v2-1.9.1 
> ./configure 
> make sudo 
> checkinstall
> cd
> ```
>
> > Remember to do the following with the script chmod +x
> >     hjb_book_creation_script.sh and run as ./hjb_book_creation_script.sh

I'm not certain how well it works but may be worth giving it a go.

Comment: They're probably better off using ffmpeg without the other libraries. See this answer at https://superuser.com/a/521939/1253299 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

[M4baker](https://github.com/crabmanX/m4baker) allows you to do this with a nice gui. You will have to build it and mp4v2 from source first, as per the ubuntu guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [m4b-tool](https://github.com/sandreas/m4b-tool/).

First, install all the dependencies

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg mp4v2-utils fdkaac php-cli php-intl php-json php-mbstring php-xml
```

Now, install / upgrade m4b-tool

```
sudo wget https://github.com/sandreas/m4b-tool/releases/download/v.0.4.2/m4b-tool.phar -O /usr/local/bin/m4b-tool && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/m4b-tool
```

To merge several mp3 into an m4b, run the command,

```
m4b-tool merge "path/to/directory/containing/mp3s/" --output-file="parth/to/merged.m4b"
```

You can also split m4bs, and create audiobooks. For details, read the README at [GitHub](https://github.com/sandreas/m4b-tool/#tldr---examples-for-the-most-common-tasks).